Expo Build React Native Apps Missing amplifyconfiguration.json
I'm building a React Native App using Amplify. App works fine and I can run it locally using npx expo start.
I'm now trying to use eas build and for both iOS and Android builds (locally or in cloud), it fails with the following error:
Error: Unable to resolve module ../amplifyconfiguration.json from /home/expo/workingdir/build/frontend/app/_layout.tsx: 
None of these files exist:
  * amplifyconfiguration.json(.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.mjs|.native.mjs|.mjs|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs|.android.scss|.native.scss|.scss|.android.sass|.native.sass|.sass|.android.css|.native.css|.css)
  * amplifyconfiguration.json/index(.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.mjs|.native.mjs|.mjs|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs|.android.scss|.native.scss|.scss|.android.sass|.native.sass|.sass|.android.css|.native.css|.css)
  21 | // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
  22 | // @ts-ignore - amplify config is git ignored, as it depends on the environment, should be generated when you pull
> 23 | import config from '../amplifyconfiguration.json';
     |                     ^
  24 | import { enGB, registerTranslation } from 'react-native-paper-dates';
  25 | import { fetchAuthSession } from 'aws-amplify/auth';

Is the only solution to somehow login to amplify in the EAS build process and pull the desired environment or have I done something wrong?

The solution was to create an .easignore file. This takes precedence over the .gitignore file.
I copied the .gitignore and excluded both amplifyconfiguration.json and aws-exports.js from it.

In your .gitignore file, you might have amplifyconfiguration.json. Just comment out this file and your build will execute just fine.

The amplifyconfiguration.json file, which contains your Amplify configuration, may not be included in your build process.
Try if these work -
Option 1: Include amplifyconfiguration.json in Your Build.

Add amplifyconfiguration.json to your project:
Run amplify pull to generate to check if amplifyconfiguration.json is 
present in your local environment or not.

If the file is excluded from your repository via .gitignore, you may need 
to include it during the build process by copying it to the appropriate 
directory before the build starts.

Option 2: Automate the Amplify Pull During Build
1.Create a script to login and pull Amplify environment:
2.Add the script to your build process:
JSON file - 
{
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "env": {
        "AMPLIFY_APP_ID": "<your-app-id>",
        "AMPLIFY_ENV_NAME": "<your-environment>"
      },
      "preBuildCommand": "bash amplify-setup.sh",
      "node": "16.x",
      "android": {
        "image": "default",
        "ndk": "21.4"
      },
      "ios": {
        "image": "default"
      }
    }
  }
}


.easignore didn't work for me.

Execute this command. base64 -i ./src/amplifyconfiguration.json
Go to your Expo page's Project secrets section. Add AMPLIFY_CONFIGURATION_BASE64 . The value is step 0's.
Add eas-build-pre-install to package.json.

"scripts": {
    "dev": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "dev:clean": "expo start -c",
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file=\"index.js\" --bundle-output=\"./ios/main.jsbundle\" --dev=false --platform=\"ios\"",
    "eas-build-pre-install": "echo $AMPLIFY_CONFIGURATION_BASE64 | base64 -d > ./src/amplifyconfiguration.json"
  },

